# mootools form validator accept blank and email validation

Tags: javascript, validation, input, mootools

I am trying to allow **Blank inputs** on my form but **also validate an email** *if ever the user inputs one*, i **already changed the regex several times** with *the ones that i find here in stackoverflow* that allows blank input but all of them doesn't work

*here is the original code:*

```
['validate-email', {
        errorMsg: Form.Validator.getMsg.pass('email'),
        test: function(element){
            return Form.Validator.getValidator('IsEmpty').test(element) || (/^(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]\.?){0,63}[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?\.)*[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\])$/i).test(element.get('value'));
        }
    }],
```

how can i allow my **mootools form validator** to **accept blanks but also verify email if there is any input**?

Direct Source: 
http://mootools.net/docs/more/Forms/Form.Validator

Comment: which mootools formcheck are you using?

Comment: @Sergio http://mootools.net/docs/more/Forms/Form.Validator

Comment: Aha, ok I though it was http://mootools.floor.ch/en/demos/formcheck/. Ok, will check

Comment: Just updated the first link in my answer. To this http://jsfiddle.net/MFcQP/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two options.

#### Option 1

Remove the `required` class from the input element. That will accept an empty value but check/validate if not empty. Try it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/MFcQP/).

#### Option 2

The one you already have :)

I normally use this regex:

```
/^[a-z0-9._%-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/i
```

Found also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8829363/2256325). Anyway, it works; check this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ff7pv/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Email validation regex is so clumsy... Does mootools support validation functions?
Anyway, you can take your regex and create a bit more clumsy one: `original-regex|^$`, which will accept empty string